# SQL: Find group of rows for consecutive days absent

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have the following `Attendance` table in my Microsoft SQL Server 2016:

```
ID         StudentID  Date          AbsenceReasonID
----------------------------------------------------
430957     10158      2018-02-02    2   
430958     10158      2018-02-03    2   
430959     10158      2018-02-04    11  
430960     12393      2018-03-15    9   
430961     1          2018-03-15    9   
430962     12400      2018-03-15    9   
430963     5959       2018-03-15    11
```

I would like to have a query that retrieves a group of rows where 3 or MORE absences have occurred consecutively by the `Date` column for a single student (`StudentID`). Ideally, the following data after running the query would be

```
ID         StudentID  Date          AbsenceReasonID
----------------------------------------------------
430957     10158      2018-02-02    2   
430958     10158      2018-02-03    2   
430959     10158      2018-02-04    11
```

Note that if a student is absent on a Friday, I would like that to carry through over the weekend to Monday (Disregard Weekend dates).

If anymore information is required to better assist you in assisting me, please let me know. I have used the following query as a starter but know it is not what I am looking for:

```
SELECT 
    CONVERT(datetime, A.DateOF, 103),
    A.SchoolNum, EI.FullName,
    COUNT(A.SchoolNum) as 'Absences'
FROM 
    Attendance A
INNER JOIN 
    EntityInformation EI ON EI.SchoolNum = A.SchoolNum AND EI.Deleted = 0
INNER JOIN 
    Enrolment E ON EI.SchoolNum = E.SchoolNum AND E.Deleted = 0
GROUP BY 
    A.SchoolNum, A.DateOf, FullName
HAVING 
    COUNT(A.SchoolNum) > 1
    AND A.DateOf = GETDATE()
    AND A.SchoolNum in (SELECT SchoolNum FROM Attendance A1 
                        WHERE A1.DateOf = A.DateOf -7)
```

This is more of a static solution that retrieves absences where the student's ID occurred twice in the past 7 days. This is neither consecutive or three or more days.

Comment: Explain what your calendar table looks like -- you know, the one that shows valid days.  Weekends would not be the only days that would be removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this to find your absence ranges. In here I use a recursive `CTE` to number all days from a few years while at the same time record their week day. Then use another recursive `CTE` to join absence dates for the same student that are one day after another, considering weekends should be skipped (read the `CASE WHEN` on the join clause). At the end show each absence spree filtered by N successive days.

```
SET DATEFIRST 1 -- Monday = 1, Sunday = 7

;WITH Days AS
(
    -- Recursive anchor: hard-coded first date
    SELECT
        GeneratedDate = CONVERT(DATE, '2017-01-01')

    UNION ALL

    -- Recursive expression: all days until day X
    SELECT
        GeneratedDate = DATEADD(DAY, 1, D.GeneratedDate)
    FROM
        Days AS D
    WHERE
        DATEADD(DAY, 1, D.GeneratedDate) <= '2020-01-01'
),
NumberedDays AS
(
    SELECT
        GeneratedDate = D.GeneratedDate,
        DayOfWeek = DATEPART(WEEKDAY, D.GeneratedDate),
        DayNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY D.GeneratedDate ASC)
    FROM
        Days AS D
),
AttendancesWithNumberedDays AS
(
    SELECT
        A.*,
        N.*
    FROM
        Attendance AS A
        INNER JOIN NumberedDays AS N ON A.Date = N.GeneratedDate
),
AbsenceSpree AS
(
    -- Recursive anchor: absence day with no previous absence, skipping weekends
    SELECT
        StartingAbsenceDate = A.Date,
        CurrentDateNumber = A.DayNumber,
        CurrentDateDayOfWeek = A.DayOfWeek,
        AbsenceDays = 1,
        StudentID = A.StudentID
    FROM
        AttendancesWithNumberedDays AS A
    WHERE
        NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT
                'no previous absence date'
            FROM
                AttendancesWithNumberedDays AS X
            WHERE
                X.StudentID = A.StudentID AND
                X.DayNumber = CASE A.DayOfWeek 
                    WHEN 1 THEN A.DayNumber - 3 -- When monday then friday (-3)
                    WHEN 7 THEN A.DayNumber - 2 -- When sunday then friday (-2)
                    ELSE A.DayNumber - 1 END)

    UNION ALL

    -- Recursive expression: find the next absence day, skipping weekends
    SELECT
        StartingAbsenceDate = S.StartingAbsenceDate,
        CurrentDateNumber = A.DayNumber,
        CurrentDateDayOfWeek = A.DayOfWeek,
        AbsenceDays = S.AbsenceDays + 1,
        StudentID = A.StudentID
    FROM
        AbsenceSpree AS S
        INNER JOIN AttendancesWithNumberedDays AS A ON
            S.StudentID = A.StudentID AND
            A.DayNumber = CASE S.CurrentDateDayOfWeek
                WHEN 5 THEN S.CurrentDateNumber + 3 -- When friday then monday (+3)
                WHEN 6 THEN S.CurrentDateNumber + 2 -- When saturday then monday (+2)
                ELSE S.CurrentDateNumber + 1 END
)
SELECT
    StudentID = A.StudentID,
    StartingAbsenceDate = A.StartingAbsenceDate,
    EndingAbsenceDate = MAX(N.GeneratedDate),
    AbsenceDays = MAX(A.AbsenceDays)
FROM
    AbsenceSpree AS A
    INNER JOIN NumberedDays AS N ON A.CurrentDateNumber = N.DayNumber
GROUP BY
    A.StudentID,
    A.StartingAbsenceDate
HAVING
    MAX(A.AbsenceDays) >= 3
OPTION
    (MAXRECURSION 5000)
```

If you want to list the original Attendance table rows, you can replace the last select:

```
SELECT
    StudentID = A.StudentID,
    StartingAbsenceDate = A.StartingAbsenceDate,
    EndingAbsenceDate = MAX(N.GeneratedDate),
    AbsenceDays = MAX(A.AbsenceDays)
FROM
    AbsenceSpree AS A
    INNER JOIN NumberedDays AS N ON A.CurrentDateNumber = N.DayNumber
GROUP BY
    A.StudentID,
    A.StartingAbsenceDate
HAVING
    MAX(A.AbsenceDays) >= 3
```

with this `CTE + SELECT`:

```
,
FilteredAbsenceSpree AS
(
    SELECT
        StudentID = A.StudentID,
        StartingAbsenceDate = A.StartingAbsenceDate,
        EndingAbsenceDate = MAX(N.GeneratedDate),
        AbsenceDays = MAX(A.AbsenceDays)
    FROM
        AbsenceSpree AS A
        INNER JOIN NumberedDays AS N ON A.CurrentDateNumber = N.DayNumber
    GROUP BY
        A.StudentID,
        A.StartingAbsenceDate
    HAVING
        MAX(A.AbsenceDays) >= 3
)
SELECT
    A.*
FROM
    Attendance AS A
    INNER JOIN FilteredAbsenceSpree AS F ON A.StudentID = F.StudentID
WHERE
    A.Date BETWEEN F.StartingAbsenceDate AND F.EndingAbsenceDate
OPTION
    (MAXRECURSION 5000)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to get the absence in a time period (let's say in past 7 days), then you can do something like this

```
 SELECT 
    ID,
    StudentID,
    [Date], 
    AbsenceReasonID
FROM(
SELECT 
    ID,
    StudentID,
    [Date], 
    AbsenceReasonID, 
    COUNT(StudentID) OVER(PARTITION BY StudentID ORDER BY StudentID) AS con, 
    ((DATEPART(dw, [Date]) + @@DATEFIRST) % 7) AS dw
FROM attendance
) D
WHERE 
     D.con > 2
AND [Date] >= '2018-02-02'
AND [Date] <= GETDATE()
AND dw NOT IN(0,1)
```

and based on your given data the output will be

```
|     ID | StudentID |       Date | AbsenceReasonID |
|--------|-----------|------------|-----------------|
| 430957 |     10158 | 2018-02-02 |               2 |
```

you could adjust the output as you like.

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/6b2a1c/3)

Comment: Thank you but I require the query to only return a group of rows where there have been 3 or more absences in a row (skipping weekends) for a single student. Furthermore, this needs to be dynamic and set to a static range of 7 days as per your query.

Comment: @ChristianTownsend sorry for hearing that, as I'm sure this wasn't mention in the post when I posted my answer ! Anyway I have updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`CTE` contains the absence dates when a student was absent on both the day before and the day after (excluding weekend). The 2 `UNION` at the end add back the first and last of each group and eliminate the duplicates.

```
with cte(id, studentId, dateof , absenceReasonId)
as
(
select a.* 
from attendance a
where exists (select 1 from attendance preva
              where preva.studentID = a.studentID
              and   datediff(day, preva.dateof, a.dateof)
                    <= (case when datepart(dw, preva.dateof) >= 5
                        then 8 - datepart(dw, preva.dateof)
                        else 1 
                        end)
              and preva.dateof < a.dateof)
and exists (select 1 from attendance nexta
              where nexta.studentID = a.studentID
              and   datediff(day, a.dateof, nexta.dateof)
                    <= (case when datepart(dw, a.dateof) >= 5
                        then 8 - datepart(dw, a.dateof)
                        else 1 
                        end)
              and nexta.dateof > a.dateof))              

select cte.*
from cte
union  -- use union to remove duplicates
select preva.* 
from
attendance preva
inner join
cte
on preva.studentID = cte.studentID
and preva.dateof < cte.dateof
and datediff(day, preva.dateof, cte.dateof)
                    <= (case when datepart(dw, preva.dateof) >= 5
                        then 8 - datepart(dw, preva.dateof)
                        else 1 
                        end) 
union
select nexta.*
from attendance nexta
inner join
cte
on nexta.studentID = cte.studentID
and   datediff(day, cte.dateof, nexta.dateof)
       <= (case when datepart(dw, cte.dateof) >= 5
                then 8 - datepart(dw, cte.dateof)
                else 1 
            end)
and nexta.dateof > cte.dateof  
order by studentId, dateof
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/8ead7/1)